# Mail visit website notification alert with content

Tags: email, web, notifications, alert

I'm trying to get a mail notification every time someone accesses a specific page within my website. This page displays users geolocation info and I want to create this alert + sent me via mail the info displayed on that page just by accessing, without pressing any buttons just an alert.

Registered visit + displayed geo info via mail.
If there is a code or something I could use, it would be very helpful!

Comment: There's an edit link under the question. Here's another one: [edit].

Comment: Also, this is far too broad. You'll need to get a start on this yourself and post back when you have something specific that we can help you with.